# Isn't this statement regarding projectile motion wrong?

Tags: kinematics, vectors, projectile

Isn't this statement regarding projectile motion wrong?

> *If a body is thrown at an angle to the horizontal with initial velocity $u$, then displacement of body as a function of time is $\vec{s}=\vec{u}t+\frac12\vec{g}t^2$. (Air drag is neglected)*

How can it be correct? Gravity acts in downward direction, so wouldn't the displacement be $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note the vector signs! The vector signs mean that direction is included in the equation. So g only has a y component, but u may have components in any direction.

Answer (score 2):

The equation

$$\vec s = \vec u t + \frac{1}{2}\vec g t^2 $$

is a *vector* equation and represents *three* equations (assuming vectors with three components $x, y, z$):

$$s_x = u_x t + \frac{1}{2} g_x t^2$$

$$s_y = u_y t + \frac{1}{2} g_y t^2$$

$$s_z = u_z t + \frac{1}{2} g_z t^2$$

Assuming $\hat z$ is the "up" direction, then

$$g_x = g_y = 0$$

$$g_z = -g$$